# Isolation forest - understanding the plot

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning

I'm a begginer with isolation forest and i started with the tutorial in this link :

https://www.kaggle.com/rgaddati/unsupervised-fraud-detection-isolation-forest

I didn't understand the first plot of path length. what does the brown color means ?

[image]

Thank you for your help

```
##All General Import Statements
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import random
%matplotlib inline
import random
from matplotlib import pyplot
import os
print(os.listdir("../input"))
class ExNode:
    def __init__(self,size):
        self.size=size

class InNode:
    def __init__(self,left,right,splitAtt,splitVal):
        self.left=left
        self.right=right
        self.splitAtt=splitAtt
        self.splitVal=splitVal

def iForest(X,noOfTrees,sampleSize):
    forest=[]
    hlim=math.ceil(math.log(sampleSize,2))
    for i in range(noOfTrees):
        X_train=df_data.sample(sampleSize)
        forest.append(iTree(X_train,0,hlim))
    return forest

def pathLength(x,Tree,currHeight):
    if isinstance(Tree,ExNode):
        return currHeight
    a=Tree.splitAtt
    if x[a]<Tree.splitVal:
        return pathLength(x,Tree.left,currHeight+1)
    else:
        return pathLength(x,Tree.right,currHeight+1)

df=pd.read_csv("../input/creditcard.csv")
y_true=df['Class']
df_data=df.drop('Class',1)

sampleSize=10000
ifor=iForest(df_data.sample(100000),10,sampleSize) ##Forest of 10 trees

posLenLst=[]
negLenLst=[]

for sim in range(1000):
    ind=random.choice(df_data[y_true==1].index)
    for tree in ifor:
        posLenLst.append(pathLength(df_data.iloc[ind],tree,0))

    ind=random.choice(df_data[y_true==0].index)
    for tree in ifor:
        negLenLst.append(pathLength(df_data.iloc[ind],tree,0))

bins = np.linspace(0,math.ceil(math.log(sampleSize,2)), math.ceil(math.log(sampleSize,2)))

pyplot.figure(figsize=(12,8))
pyplot.hist(posLenLst, bins, alpha=0.5, label='Anomaly')
pyplot.hist(negLenLst, bins, alpha=0.5, label='Normal')
pyplot.xlabel('Path Length')
pyplot.ylabel('Frequency')
pyplot.legend(loc='upper left')
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code, as links can go stale.

Comment: Have you tried to reach the tutorial authors?

Comment: I added the code and to be honest i didn't try to reach the tutorial authors..

Comment: I can't reach the tutorial authors, the page doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

The brown look likes a mix of the tan and blue. So I think thats where they overlap. This is evident because the alpha of each is .5

Further Explained: The colors are mixing where they overlap. Its plotting the blue then if the tan is also there it plots it on top. Since the colors have alpha of .5 which alpha is transparency the colors are mixing. Resulting in a brown where they overlap. Try plotting each separately and you will see that they will overlap.

Comment: Could you please explain more ? I still do not understand